# Many-to-Many seqelize-typescript not unique constraint key issue

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, sequelize-typescript, junction-table

I have some issue with save the entity in postgres db with the same constraint key via my rest api service.

I have a **pre-condtition** - structure of entities should looks like this:

- **Customer** has many **Resources** ( 1 to n)
- Many **Resources** belongs to 1 **Datacenter** (n to 1)

As I correct understand pre-condition I implement many-to-many association  for customer-resource-datacenter, where Resources is junstion table [many-to-many diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRhM2.png)

When I try to create resource POST /api/resources- its proceed ok.

```
{"app": "test_app", "customerId": "0001", "datacenterId": "0002"}
```

But when I try do next POST /api/resources request with the same pair of key

```
{"app": "test_app_1",  "customerId": "0001", "datacenterId": "0002" }
```

I get 500 Error because of ***Key ("customerId", "datacenterId")=(0001, 0002) already exists***.

So my first **question** is it actually acceptable - store the same pairs of foreign keys in junction table or it is impossible?
And if yes - How I can reach it? ***Have I actually correctly defined the structure of the relationship between entities based on pre-condition???***

I am using [sequlize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) for orm and there is my code ->

**Customer entity model:**

```
@Table
export class Customer extends Model {
@Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
})
uuid: string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
})
name: string;

@BelongsToMany(() => Datacenter, () => Resource, 'customerId')
datacenters: Datacenter[]

@HasMany(() => Resource)
resources: Resource[]
}
```

**Datacenter entity model:**

```
@Table
export class Datacenter extends Model {
@Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
})
uuid: string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
})
name: string;

@BelongsToMany(() => Customer,() => Resource, 'datacenterId')
customers: Customer[]

@HasMany(() => Hardware)
hardware: Hardware[]
}
```

**Resource entity model**

```
@Table
export class Resource extends Model {
@Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
})
uuid: string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
})
app_identifier: string;

@ForeignKey(() => Customer)
@Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
})
customerId: string;

@BelongsTo(() => Customer)
customer: Customer;

@ForeignKey(() => Datacenter)
@Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
})
datacenterId: string;
}
```

**Function to persist entity:**

```
async create(resource: ResourceDto): Promise<Resource> {
    return await this.resourceRepository.create<Resource>({...resource});
}
```

I also tried do something like this:

```
    @BelongsToMany(() => Datacenter, {through: {model: Resource, unique: false}})
    datacenters: Datacenter[]
```

But it doesnt even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pre-conditions don't lead to many-to-many. You would need many-to-many only when `Resource` will be a reference table with unique resources that you can link to certain customers as many times as you want (in this case you also will need a junction table CustomerResource).

In your case, you have **customer** resources that each have a link to a datacenter as a link to a reference table with unique datacenter records that can be used many times in different resources.
So you need exactly the same relationships that are declared in pre-conditions:

```
User.hasMany(Resource)
Resource.belongsTo(User)
Resource.belongsTo(Datacenter)
```

That said you need to remove both `@BelongsToMany` definitions and use already defined `@BelongsTo` and `@HasMany`.

Comment: yes, my bad - I just looked at pre condition and mixed it up with many-to-many relationship. Thanks! 
The main reason why I did it, just because I need get datacenters by customerId and for many-to-many, that I have implemented I just wrote it 
`customerRepository.findOne({where: [customerId}, include: [{model: Datacenter, through: {attributes: []}}]})` what means LEFT OUTER JOIN statement in legacy. But now since your tip I lost direct assosiation between Datacenter and Customer, so now I need rework this statement =)

Comment: You still can include Datacenter in Resource while including the latter in `customerRepository.findOne`